# How to parse POST array data in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to send JSON data with an array to an AWS Lambda function, but I can't parse the array.

In the frontend I'm requesting this way:

```
const ids = ['long_id1', 'long_id2', 'long_id3'];

const request = await fetch(
  'https://ID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/endpoint',
  {
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userIds: ids
    }),
    method: 'POST'
 }
)
const response = JSON.parse(await request.text());
```

In the lambda I have the following code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(event); //also tried: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event)) because I saw someone recommending it

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(parsed)
  }

}
```

But I get `event.body` as a string. For example if I log the `event` variable I get:

```
event: {
  ...,
  body: "{\"userIds\":[\"long_id1\",\"long_id2\",\"long_id3\"]}"
}
```

But, if I try to parse the body, it throws this error:

```
ERROR   SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:11:23)
    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)
2021-08-08T07:43:05.425Z 5feeddb7-6254-405d-b311-42924abc5f4d ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:11:23) at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

## **Update**

Not sure if was some kind of typo but now I'm able to get the data properly. I'm just doing what @Mark B said with the following code in the lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { userIds } = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const result = await doSomethingWithUserIds(userIds)

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(result)
  }

}
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Why are you taking the event object, converting it to JSON, converting it back from JSON, then converting it to JSON again?

Comment: "it throws an error" — What error do you get?

Comment: "I try to parse it," — Which of the multiple times you parse something in your code are you talking about here?

Comment: hi @Quentin, thanks for showing me how I can improve my question. I just updated here the error. I tried converting it to JSON and then it back from JSON because I saw someone recommending it. But I get the same error regardless

Comment: As I understand, you did `const parsed =  JSON.parse(event.body)` and it throws a syntax error ? What does it print when you console.log it ? Is it valid Json?

Comment: @AntoninRiche I received a body equals to `"{\"userIds\":[\"long_id1\",\"long_id2\",\"long_id3\"]}"`. If I parse this string in the browser console I can get the array info correctly.

Comment: `event` is an object. You don't need to parse that into JSON, it's already a JSON object. `event.body` is a string. You need to parse that property of the `event` object into JSON. `JSON.parse(event.body)`.

Comment: @MarkB do you mind writing up an answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is an object. You don't need to parse that into JSON, it's already a JSON object. `event.body` is a string. You need to parse that property of the `event` object into JSON.

```
JSON.parse(event.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if was some kind of typo but now I'm able to get the data properly. I'm just doing what @Mark B said with the following code in the lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { userIds } = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const result = await doSomethingWithUserIds(userIds)

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(result)
  }

}
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: A better option would be to ask @MarkB to write up an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, I didn't think this before. I'm going to ask him :)